# How to correct the winding order of shapes coming out of d3-contour?

Tags: d3.js, mapbox, geojson

I created contour lines from gridded data using [`d3-contour`](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour). Unfortunately I'm having trouble rendering shapes with holes properly on a mapbox map. Holes appear as an additional layer on top of the outer shape instead of cutting a hole. When drawing the same data using observable plot, the shapes are rendered correctly however. I suppose this has something to do with the winding order which is somehow handled [differently in d3](https://observablehq.com/@d3/winding-order). Trying to fix the winding order using [`@turf/rewind`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/rewind) did not bring me any further unfortunately.

To illustrate the case, I created this [observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/bfc264ebdcd70e2b). How would I go about correcting the winding order?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I don't fully understand why however. Using `@turf/rewind` or an adaptation of [this rewind function](https://observablehq.com/@fil/rewind) works. BUT it works only if it is applied before projecting the contours to geo/spherical coordinates.

I added the solution to the [observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/bfc264ebdcd70e2b)

Comment: Cool! I do think it's worth mentioning that both methods that "fix" the GeoJSON via rewind (whether through Turf or Mapshaper) introduce artifacts. If I zoom into your map just a bit, for example, I see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvAar.png). That might be fixable by snapping points that are close together into a single point at some step. I haven't tried it. The SVG approach does not suffer from this defect.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the Mapbox documentation doesn't indicate a way to specify an even-odd fill rule when filling GeoJSON polygons. I could've missed it but [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/7930a1a1df106da5) presents two alternative solutions.

The first suggests that you fix the holes using [MapShaper](https://mapshaper.org/). To do so, simply upload your GeoJSON, open the MapShaper console, and execute

```
clean rewind
```

The second solution uses D3 to overlay an SVG on top of the map. This works since SVG does implement an even-odd winding rule. The Javascript code is a bit more complicated, since it needs to coordinate the two images. It works pretty well, though, and it does so on the fly.

In both cases, you get a map that looks a lot like so:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your answer. What I need to do however is to do this dynamically in the browser. Do you happen to know what type of tooling mapshaper uses in the background to do the rewinding?

Comment: Ahh - when you mentioned that you tried Turf, I guessed that a solution where you modified the data file was acceptable. I modified my response and the linked notebook to suggest a second alternative that uses D3 to overlay an SVG on top of the map. I don't *think* there's a pure Mapbox solution but I might have missed it. I know Mapbox pretty well but I know D3 much better still.

Comment: I figured it out (see answer above). Thanks for your help though.